# {% block content %} {% endblock %} displayed as text

Tags: flask, jinja2

I'm going through an [online tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI&list=PL7AeU6Jfo1ue-VZ6SI9x0EOCW2hhGC1l6&index=4&t=2214s) on python web development.

However, despite double check all the codes are the same, I can't get visual studio to
recognize the `{% block content %} {% endblock %}` as a part of the code.

The expected output should be only the contents between `{% block content %} {% endblock %}`, however, *'{% block content %} {% endblock %}'* is displayed as plain text on the web page, which is not expected behavior.

And the rest of the codes on other templates did not work as well.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
         ...
        <title>
            {% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
        </title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class = "collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="login" href="/login">Login</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="SignUp" href="/sign_up">Sign Up</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="logout" href="/logout">Log Out</a>
                <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="home" href="/home">Home</a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <div class="container">{% block content %} {% endblock %}</div>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems that VS Code does not recognize this syntax, maybe I need to configure some setting for it to work but I can't find it, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: are passing the right context from your views.py ?

Comment: `from flask import Blueprint, render_template

#this file is a blueprint for the application

views = Blueprint('views', __name__) #name of the blueprint

@views.route('/')
def home(): #will run whenever we go the root defined
    return render_template("home.html")`   Yes, here's the code from views.py

Comment: add url you're trying to open to the question and show urls.py file contents

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1f0ab3ahPHMxgOf4vPq_6LrAuqQNmmrjK/view?usp=sharing                  Hi here's a google drive link which all the files related to this question are uploaded.

Comment: show the code, not links to code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is NOT Django!  It is Flask.  And this has nothing to do with VS Code, either.  If VS Code doesn't "recognize" the syntax, it has to do with the language it is detecting, which shows you the pretty colors, but it will have no affect on the code itself.  If yo want to install **jinja** into your VS Code checkout https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wholroyd.jinja.  The code from your comment works fine on my machine, although the one in your Google Drive link was a bit different, and had an error.  So I figured you fixed it?  If not, let me know, and I can help.

Comment: @Raphael   Hi Raphael, could you please share the error found?

Comment: Your comment has this at the end: `return render_template("home.html")` but the one in your Google drive says something like `return render_template("template/base.html")`.

Answer (score 0):

For your line "{% block content %} {% endblock %}" put these on separate lines like this:

```
<div class="container">
{% block content %} 
{% endblock %}
</div>
```

Also check VSC settings so it doesn't reformat this code for you.

That's how my tutorial does it.